# Location-based Twitter search

Tags: search, twitter

I want to execute a Location-based Twitter search using the location operator.
I have tried using the url http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=location:New York
But it returns the records with the search word "New York"

Can anyone please tell how to use the location operator for twitter search?

Comment: While I'm here, I noticed that you have asked 11 questions and accepted 0 answers.  Please don't be a jerk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also check out the "near" and "within" operators: http://search.twitter.com/operators

Answer (score 1):

I came across this from a search on google.

According the Twitter's own API Guide
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search

"near: cannot be used in API search"

near will work for web based searches but asking for .json or .atom files and the search system will ignore the near operator. (See original post's url, its using the API request for .atom)

the apiwiki does say the "location" operator should work, however I have been unable to verify that it works in this way.

Hope this helps anyone else who comes across this from google as well

Answer (score 0):

this should work

http://search.twitter.com/search?q=&ands=&phrase=&ors=&nots=&tag=&lang=all&from=&to=&ref=&near=new+york&within=15&units=mi&since=&until=&rpp=15